# how to detect index cell in uiview class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I have 3 class (`UIView` & `UITableViewCell` & `UIViewController`).
I have `UITableview` `Outlet` in my `UIViewController` and load cells from `UITableViewCell` for it.
also I have one View `Outlet` in my `UITableViewCell` that has `ViewCell` class.

now my `UIView` Class (`ViewCell`) has this code :

```
@implementation ViewCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        //[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

    }
    return self;
}
-(void)singleTap:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == tap.state)
    {
        NSLog(@"single");
        // I want to detect indexPath my cell when tap on every cell this here!!!
    }
}
-(void)doubleTap:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == tap.state)
    {
        NSLog(@"double");
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
 // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.*/

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer* doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
    doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    doubleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

    UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
    [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

    [[self layer] setCornerRadius:4.0f];
    [[self layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];


}

@end
```

when I run my code and I tap on View in my `UITableViewCell` I want to detect cell's indexPath of my table in `singleTap` method and `NSLog` to me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not create the recognizers inside the drawRect.

Second: Please do not use tags for this, as proposed by Vijay. Instead use the mechanism of delegation.

another Hint: The name ViewCell would tell me, it is a subclass of UITableViewCell, while CellView would indicate it is a UIView subclass that probably should be used in a cell.

But now to answer this question with delegation:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class CellView;

@protocol CellViewTapDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) singleTapOnCellView:(CellView *)cellView;
-(void) doubleTapOnCellView:(CellView *)cellView;
@end

@interface CellView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id<CellViewTapDelegate> delegate;
-(id) parentCell;
@end
```

---

```
#import "CellView.h"

@implementation CellView

-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer* doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(doubleTap:)];
        doubleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

        UITapGestureRecognizer* singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [singleTap requireGestureRecognizerToFail:doubleTap];
        [self addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];


        [[self layer] setCornerRadius:4.0f];
        [[self layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];

    }

    return self;
}

-(id)parentCell
{
    return [[self superview] superview];
}

-(void)singleTap:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == tap.state)
    {
        if (self.delegate) {
            [self.delegate singleTapOnCellView:self];
        }
    }
}
-(void)doubleTap:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == tap.state)
    {
        if (self.delegate) {
            [self.delegate doubleTapOnCellView:self];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

The CellView has a delegate property it will send the messages `singleTapOnCellView:` and `doubleTapOnCellView:`

The CellView is designed to be used in a cell's contentView, there-for it can access it's cell by

```
-(id)parentCell
{
    return [[self superview] superview];
    //                ^            ^
    //                |            |
    //             contentView     |
    //                            cell
}
```

This allows os to ask the tableView for the indexPath of the cell.

To ensure this, I created an UITableViewCell subclass that will a CellView on it's contentView, I did this in the storyboard.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@class CellView;


@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet CellView *cellView;
@end
```

Now I let my ViewController implement the table view's datasource and the CellView's delegate

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "MyTableViewCell.h"
#import "CellView.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, CellViewTapDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHue:(indexPath.row / 30.0) saturation:1 brightness:1 alpha:1];

    return cell;
}

-(void)singleTapOnCellView:(CellView *)cellView
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [cellView parentCell];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSLog(@"single tap: %@", path);
}


-(void)doubleTapOnCellView:(CellView *)cellView
{
    MyTableViewCell *cell = [cellView parentCell];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    NSLog(@"double tap: %@", path);
}
@end
```

You find the complete code, including the storybaord, here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/17284613/TapCellView.zip

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you create the cell, set the indexPath as Tag of Your cell & your outlet View.
in cellForRowAtIndexPath method, you should do like this

```
        UITableViewCellYourCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier"];

        cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.row;
        cell.yourCustomView.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Then detect like this

```
-(void)singleTap:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)tap
{
    if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded == tap.state)
    {
        NSLog(@"single");

        NSLog(@"Tapped on index:%i",tap.view.tag);// By using taped view
        NSLog(@"Tapped on index:%i",tap.view.superview.tag);// By using cell contentView


        // I want to detect indexPath my cell when tap on every cell this here!!!
    }
}
```

I would recommend you to add recogniser on custom view initialization point.

Comment: working my friend but I can't access to property in my UITableViewCells for example (Name & Detail) these is two property in my UITableViewCell